# Get default CellFormat for a new cell

Tags: openxml

I am using OpenXml to load in an existing Excel file (a template, with formatting, background-colors, etc) and I want to paste some numeric data into one of the Worksheets.

Supposing I'm writing a value to, say, cell D3, but the Excel file doesn't currently contain a `<Cell>` element for this cell... but the user has set all values in the D column to be centered and to show 2 decimal places...  how can I get this `CellFormat` or `StyleIndex` to use in my new cell ?

I can't use the following code, as it's a brand new `<Cell>` element, so the `StyleIndex` value will be *null*:

```
CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)wbPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ElementAt((int)cell.StyleIndex.Value);
```

Is there a way to find out that my new `<Cell>` element needs a particular *StyleIndex*, based on the inherited style (i.e. I've set all cells in the D column to be centered..?)

[image]